# C++ Displaying a Vector when using a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, runtime

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
     unsigned int numVec;
     unsigned int input;

     std::cout << "Enter Number of Vectors: ";
     std::cin >> numVec;

     std::vector<int>* Vec;
     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numVec; i++)
     {
          std::cout << "Enter Vector Value " << i << ": ";
          std::cin >> input;
          Vec->push_back(input);
     }
     std::cout << std::endl;
     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Vec->size(); i++)
     {
          std::cout << "Value at Index (" << i << ") " <<  Vec->at(i) << std::endl;
     }
     std::cout << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

I am trying to learn how Vectors work as it is a topic that i have withheld learning for a very long time for no apparently reason.

**My above code will compile and run however once i put in a number to store in the Vector it will crash**.

The program did work before when i was just using a vector without the pointer but just for learning reasons i wanted to try it with a pointer, I am just wondering what am i doing wrong with this code and if someone could possibly flame me for doing something or give me some good advice on what i am doing wrong in this situation so i can learn for future reference.

Comment: `std::vector<int>* Vec;` There is something missing here.

Comment: @InternetAussie: Please, comments are not for answers.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

`std::vector<int>* Vec;`

with

`std::vector<int> vec;`

and replace the pointer to member operator `->` with the member selection operator `.`.

Only on rare occasions do you need to use dynamic storage for a `std::vector` instance, as that class does an excellent job of managing the memory for you. Currently you are not allocating any memory for your vector, and the behaviour of your code is *undefined*.

If you *must* use a pointer then write

`std::vector<int>* vec = new std::vector();`

and don't forget to call `delete vec;` when you're done. Consider using `std::unique_ptr` &c. so the `delete` is taken care of automatically.

Comment: Well, they shouldn't; at least not at first. That's the "good advice" bit. But I've added the `new` syntax nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

> My above code will compile and run however once i put in a number to store in the Vector it will crash.

What vector?

You never created a vector.

You only created a pointer, one which (a) is uninitialised, and (b) does not point to anything, let alone a (c) vector.